# CRM Dynamics 2013 Get Connections in entity by Connection Role

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I am new to CRM Dynamics and very novice in development for it.  I have the following situation at hand which is as follows:

I have an Account entity which can have multiple connections to it.  Through code, SDK, I am trying to retrieve all the connections which are of a specific connection role.  So far I am able to get all connections related to the Account Entity, however I am not able to determine what business role they have.  Can someone help please?

```
 OrganizationServiceContext _orgContext = new OrganizationServiceContext(service);

        try
        {
            connections = (from conn in _orgContext.CreateQuery<Connection>()
                            where conn.Record1Id.Id == account.Id
                            select conn).ToList();
```

I wish that in this LINQ statement (where clause) I can filter out on those with a specific connection role.

Also can someone guide me to good ebooks regarding development for CRM Dynamics 2013

Answer (score 0):

you are using **Late Bound Queries**. you can write **Linq standard Query Operators** with the help of OrganizationServiceContext class.

try this

```
var connections = _orgContext.CreateQuery("connection").ToList().Where(w=>w.Id==account.Id).Select(s=>s);
```